# Varhandles and volatile and memory access

Tags: java, volatile

I am trying to understand Varhandles but some examples contain different approaches to the visibility of a variable.

E.g.

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
class Point {
   volatile int x;
   private static final VarHandle X;
   static {
     try {
       X = MethodHandles.lookup().
           findVarHandle(Point.class, "x",
                         int.class);
     } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
       throw new Error(e);
     }
   }
   // ...
}
```

Example shows x field that is volatile. Is it necessary? I mean if you have a volatile field then we have a memory barrier and other mechanisms related to program order etc. but from my perspective in that example volatile is not necessary otherwise it has a significant impact on performance and from the other side, Varhandle provides all necessary instrumentation to do this safely.

What is the proper solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

`Varhandle` has [`getVolatile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#getVolatile(java.lang.Object...)) / [`setVolatile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#setVolatile(java.lang.Object...)) that can access `x` is if it where declared volatile:

> Returns the value of a variable, with memory semantics of reading as if the variable was declared `volatile`.

But that only handles the case when you access `x` through the `VarHandle`.

If any code accesses `x` directly you **still** need to declare it as volatile because otherwise the JIT is still allowed to cache `x` in an internal register and read it only once - for example in the following code:

```
while (x < 10) {
    // do something with x
}
```

From a performance point this will not matter - accessing `x` through the `VarHandle` cannot be faster than accessing `x` directly. (There might be an exception if you declare `x` as volatile but access it through the `VarHandle`s `get()` method that doesn't observe volatile semantics - but then you will run into concurrency issues.)

Comment: Hmm, it makes sense but from that perspective field always must be marked as volatile ? Because we want to be sure that value is updated before other thread read it

Comment: @Matrix12 not necessarily. Maybe the field is only ever accessed from a single thread. Or it is only accessed while the thread accessing it is holding a lock.

Comment: I agree with that, but if the field is accessible by a single thread then var handle doesn't make sense, is it?

Comment: @Matrix12 a `VarHandle` can be used as a replacement for a `java.lang.reflect.Field` with an easier API (checked exceptions are only thrown when creating the `VarHandle`, not when accessing the value through `get()` / `set()`). And IMHO using reflection (even when working with a single thread) **is** a useful concept - and by extension this also applies to `VarHandle`.

Comment: I agree with you. One question, the field should be public or private that is handled by Varhandle, I mean field x should be public or private??